# List Item Deletion Not Working C#

Tags: c#

I have a list that's pulling information from the database and populating the rows.

I've finally got rid of the errors where I couldn't find the control but the delete button isn't running properly, the page reloads but doesn't take any action against the database.

My thinking is that the list item doesn't itself need to get deleted as the list is populated on page load from the database, including post back so it just won't bring through the row that got deleted.

Can someone point me in the right direction of where I'm going wrong please?

**Edit**

As pointed out below I have made changes to the GetData() function by removing the using:

```
using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        sda.Fill(ds);
                        return ds;
                    }
```

However the below snippet of ASP listview isn't being brought back to the theeLbl.Text to be used as the control ID which was the main issue.

```
<asp:ListView ID="List1" runat="server" GroupItemCount="3" GroupPlaceholderID="gph1" ItemPlaceholderID="iph1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="uCompanylbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("uCompanyId")%>'></asp:Label>
                </td>
```

**C# Code:**

```
protected void deleteBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalConnection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        string query = @"DELETE FROM EndUser WHERE @someId = EndUser.uCompanyID;
                        DELETE FROM Company WHERE @someId = Company.Id;
                        DELETE FROM BAD WHERE @someId = BAD.Id;";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            int deleted = 0;
            try
            {
                var theLbl = this.List1.FindControl("uCompanylbl") as Label;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@someId", theLbl.Text);
                con.Open(); ;
                deleted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch(Exception er)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(er.ToString());
            }

        }
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        List1.DataSource = this.GetData();
        List1.DataBind();
    }               
}

private DataSet GetData()
{
    // add connection code for error handling
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalConnection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SelectProc", con))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    sda.Fill(ds);
                    return ds;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not rebinding your list after the delete button event?

Comment: Remove the using on DataSet ds, then will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR - this should solve your problem, any issues please let me know!

Not entirely sure on what it is that is going wrong with your code as not all of it is there. That being said I have recently had a similar issue where I was trying to get hold of the index of the selected item in the list, but it wasn't actually selected.

I've tried to blend your code with mine so that you will be able to see where the errors are occurring and make slight amends to get yours up and running. If there are any issues please let me know and I'll try to make amends.

You can do this in the backend C# or ASP for this example I accessed the DB through SQL datasource within the ASP.

**ASP:**

```
    <asp:ListView ID="List1" runat="server" GroupItemCount="3" GroupPlaceholderID="gph1" ItemPlaceholderID="iph1" DataSourceID="sqlDataSource1">
                <ItemTemplate>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="uCompanylbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("uCompanyId")%>'/>
                    </td>
<td>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="Select" runat="server" Text="Select" Font-Bold="true" CommandName="Select" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SelectedItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="hiding" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("uCompanyId")%>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Button ID="deleteBtn" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClick="deleteBtn_Click1"/>
                        </td>
    </tr>
    </SelectedItemTemplate>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDatasource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LocalConnection%>" SelectCommand="SelectProc" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="true" DataSourceMode="DataReader">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

You may have some back end code that already works but I thought best to show exactly how I go this working: finding the list control by id through the selected index (the link button in the asp that takes you to the selectedtemplate) add in the name of the controol id to get the value which in my case was the DB value I'm looking for, then convert the string to int and pass to the stored procedure (don't use string queries if you can help it) and all the db stuff that selects/deletes whatever.

**C#:**

```
protected void deleteBtn_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalConnection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DeleteProc", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    try
                    {
                        ListViewItem item = List1.Items[List1.SelectedIndex];
                        Label hdn = (Label)item.FindControl("hiding");
                        string tmp = hdn.Text;
                        int sId = Int32.Parse(tmp);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("someId", sId);
                        con.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception error)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(error.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
                    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(ds);
                        return ds;
                    }
```

Do you realize, that this means that you `Dispose` your DataSet before it's returned?

Comment: Rebuilt without the using - cheers, upvoted but still need to find why the list control value isn't being brought back.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in another way

```
dataset ds= new dataset();
sda.fill(ds);
return ds;
```